# Why is File Upload breaking multiple things

Tags: php, javascript

My web app runs well except one thing.  File Uplods.  Basically when a user logs on and submits their information, after validation on client and server side, their file is uploaded programtically by javascript using the submit method.  Once the file is submitted php inlcudes the main page for the user to view.

The issue I'm having is that now when the user hits reload from the main page IE pops up a window saying that informatin needs to be resent again.  I don't know what information IE is referring to.  But I don't want this window popping up.

Also now when the user logs out, it does not work because the $_FILES super global is still set from the file upload.  This effectively breaks the signout as the error is displayed to the browser.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong as $_FILES is not being cleared after the submit...and IE seems to think that there is some "information" that the user needs to be alerted to on reloads.

But the SignIn and TryIts all work as I expected; it is the SignUp which inlcudes the file upload which breaks these two things.

I'm not sure what code to post, but let me know and I can post what is needed

Comment: After POST request it is usually good to do a 303/302 redirect so this dialog won't come up. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: The Form POSTS information to the server if the `action` attribute is set to POST, so most likely yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different PHP file (different URL) for submit action.

After processing your file upload, redirect back to where you want to be using:

```
header("Location: http://your.server/your_path/");
```

Comment: I just fixed it using this...except I used...        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">';

Comment: Cool! You are right, it's possible to do it like that too. Note however, that in most cases it is not recommended to use meta refresh. See if this clarifies things: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Comment: or header( "refresh:0;url=wherever.php" );...4 ways total to do a reload from the server..I can think of...seems like header() of some sort is the "best practice"